# How to say 治安不好 in English

Tags: translation

How would you say 治安不好 in English?

Someone told me it means "*not safe*", but I am not sure about it. It seems too broad. 治安 is the safety level of a place specifically relating to crimes, but being not safe may refer to avalanche or smog.

Comment: cf。jukuu： 5 examples for 治安不好: 1,2: poor public order,3,4: public security (order ?) is poor,looking up "law and order" jukuu has 2 examples among first 10 with 治安 translated as such:  1.The army was called in to restore law and order to the place.
 军队被召来恢复该地治安。3.  The police are responsible for the preservation of law and order.
 警察负责维持治安。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a comment about law and order/public safety. So, e.g. it could translate as "Public safety is bad."

Comment: Is it a common usage?

Comment: I mean is it a big word used by politicians in speech or it can be a colloquial word in daily life? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Superuser
Do you mean the English word "public safety"?

Comment: @ Drunken Master Yes. Is public safety a big word?

Comment: It's an ordinary word, not formal, not colloquial, nothing special about it. Check any dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

I guess "high-crime" makes more sense.

> 治安不好的小区
>
> high-crime neighborhood